# C++: Help me finding a bug - 2D array search -

Tags: c++, arrays, search

My program asks for numbers and places them in a 2D array.
Then it asks for a number and performs a search, after which it prints position for said number within the 2D array.

Search function has a bug that adds 1 to expected row position. "Fixed" it by substracting 1 to "row" variable, but it is ovb not acceptable.

Currently feeling kind of dumb about this, help will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define R 3
#define C 2    

typedef int matrix[R][C];

void input(matrix m)
{
int i, j;
i = j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i< R; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < C; j++)
        { 
            cout << "Row " << i << " Column " << j << ": ";
            cin >> m[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void search(int x, matrix m, int& row, int& column)
{
int r, c;
bool OK;
OK = false;
r = 0;

    while((!OK) && (r < R)) 
    {
        c = 0;
        while((!OK) && (c < C))
        {
            if(m[r][c] == x)
                OK = true;
            else
                c++;
        }
        r++;    
    }

    column = c;
    row = r-1;  //LOL
}



int main()
{
    matrix mat;
    int number;
    int row;
    int column;

    input(mat);

    cout << "Which number are you looking for?: ";
    cin >> number;
    search(number, mat, row, column);
    cout << endl << "Row " << row << " Column: " << column;

    fflush stdin;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the value is found the code must ensure that `r` is not incremented (see code below the if statement is used to check if value has been found). Also `row` is not assigned from `r` at the end of the search function.

```
void search(int x, matrix m, int& row, int& column)
{
    int r, c;
    bool OK = false;
    r = 0;

    while((!OK) && (r < R))
    {
        c = 0;
        while((!OK) && (c < C))
        {
            if(m[r][c] == x)
                OK = true;
            else
                c++;
        }
        if (!OK)
            r++;
    }    
    column = c;
    row = r;
}
```

Comment: Ty man! if (!OK) r++; fixed it! Didn't need break statement. Are you sure there is a need for it?

Comment: Glad to hear it;s working. You are right - break is not needed because the c++ statement is in the else clause.

Comment: ps you should accept the most useful answer - it's the done thing here :)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the matrix by reference to `input`:

```
void input(matrix& m)
```

otherwise you are not populating the matrix.

I'd also recommend to transform this:

```
#define R 3
#define C 2
```

to:

```
const std::size_t R = 3;
const std::size_t C = 2;
```

And finally I'd suggest you to take a look at [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search).

Comment: My understnding is that arrays are passed by reference by default. So there is no need to add &. Is that wrong?

Comment: @MV_81, nothing is passed by reference unless you are putting a `&`. Arrays sometimes decay to pointers, but pointers are not references in any shape or form.

Comment: Yes! Ty, trying to mark it as solved but I'm not finding the button.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to not increment `r` if `OK` is true.

You could also replace the `while` loops with their `for` equivalents.

```
for(r = 0; !OK && r < R; r += 1)
{
    for(c = 0; !OK && c < C; c += 1)
    {
        OK = (m[r][c] == x);
    }
}
```

That would prevent `r` being incremented if `OK` is true.